# Using for loop to create multiple ggplots

Tags: r, for-loop, ggplot2

```
p[[2]]<-ggplot(data = icadata, aes(x = icadata[[2]])) + geom_histogram()    
p[[3]]<-ggplot(data = icadata, aes(x = icadata[[3]])) + geom_histogram()    
p[[4]]<-ggplot(data = icadata, aes(x = icadata[[4]])) + geom_histogram()    
p[[5]]<-ggplot(data = icadata, aes(x = icadata[[5]])) + geom_histogram()    
p[[6]]<-ggplot(data = icadata, aes(x = icadata[[6]])) + geom_histogram()    
p[[7]]<-ggplot(data = icadata, aes(x = icadata[[7]])) + geom_histogram()    
p[[8]]<-ggplot(data = icadata, aes(x = icadata[[8]])) + geom_histogram()    
p[[9]]<-ggplot(data = icadata, aes(x = icadata[[9]])) + geom_histogram()    
p[[10]]<-ggplot(data = icadata, aes(x = icadata[[10]])) + geom_histogram()    
p[[11]]<-ggplot(data = icadata, aes(x = icadata[[11]])) + geom_histogram()    
p[[12]]<-ggplot(data = icadata, aes(x = icadata[[12]])) + geom_histogram()    
p[[13]]<-ggplot(data = icadata, aes(x = icadata[[13]])) + geom_histogram()    
p[[16]]<-ggplot(data = icadata, aes(x = icadata[[16]])) + geom_histogram()    

p <- list()    
for(i in c(2:13,16) ) {      
           p[[i]]<-ggplot(data = icadata, aes(x = icadata[[i]])) + geom_histogram()    
}
```

What's the difference between the codes above?
Why do I get always the same picture after runnning the for loop code?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Zhi li, this makes very little sense without some context, please realize that nobody else knows what you do about `icadata`. Please make this question *reproducible*. This includes sample code (including listing non-base R packages), sample *unambiguous* data (e.g., `dput(head(x))` or `data.frame(x=...,y=...)`), and expected output. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Comment: Every time `ggplot` is called, it overwrites the previous plots and draw new plots on a fresh canvas, then displays that last plot drawn. This is why you get only the last plot every time you run the code, because the loop makes a new plot every iteration. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to get all the histgrams of numerical variables in my icadata.It's  inconvenientto plot one-by-one,so I  try to use this for-loop to plot them and save them in a list.Do you know how to correct it?Thanks.

Comment: You want to get all the histograms into one plot? That would be unreadable. Using facets instead would be more helpful.

Comment: Not in one plot,I want to use a list to save them.

Answer (score 1):

if you look at the plot you get, it is the last plot that appears. ggplot2 only evaluates the function when you call it. And by entering the x value as icadata[[i]], ggplot2 only plots the icadata[[16]].

So if you do need to use the for loop, it is much better to point it directly to the column inside icadata:

```
icadata = data.frame(sapply(1:16,function(i)rnorm(100,i,1)))

for(i in c(2:13,16) ) {
COLUMN=colnames(icadata)[i]
p[[i]]<-ggplot(data = icadata, aes_(x = as.name(COLUMN))) + geom_histogram()  
# or use 
# p[[i]]<-ggplot(data = icadata, aes_string(x = COLUMN)) + geom_histogram()    
}  

grid.arrange(grobs=p[c(2:13,16)])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(reshape2)
d <- melt(icadata[,-c(1,14,15)])
ggplot(d,aes(x = value)) + 
  facet_wrap(~variable,scales = "free_x") + 
  geom_histogram()
```

I tried facets instead.It worked.But I am still confused why I can't get a plot list using  that for-loop code unless I plot them one-by-one like the very beginning of my code.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to reproduce the observed behaviour using the `mtcars` dataset. To me, it seems that the way how `aes(x = icadata[[2]])` is specified might be the issue.

The code below does work for me:

```
icadata <- as.data.frame(mtcars) # create reproducible data
library(ggplot2)

p <- list()    
for(i in c(2:3, 6)) {
  p[[i]] <- ggplot(data = icadata, aes(x = !!sym(names(icadata)[i]))) + geom_histogram()    
}
```

Output is a list as requested by the OP

```
class(p)
```

> ```
> [1] "list"
> ```

with the list elements either empty or a `ggplot` object

```
lapply(p, class)
```

> ```
> [[1]]
> [1] "NULL"
>
> [[2]]
> [1] "gg"     "ggplot"
>
> [[3]]
> [1] "gg"     "ggplot"
>
> [[4]]
> [1] "NULL"
>
> [[5]]
> [1] "NULL"
>
> [[6]]
> [1] "gg"     "ggplot"
> ```

I am able to plot the whole list by

```
lapply(p, print)
```

or a single graph with, e.g.,

```
p[[3]]
```

[image]

Please, note that the x-axis is labeled by the column name, e.g., `disp` instead of `icadata[[3]]`.

---

If desired, the `for` loop can be replaced by a call to `lapply()` which returns a `list` object without empty elements. In addition, the list elements can be named appropriately.

```
cols <- names(icadata)[c(2:3, 6)]
p2 <- lapply(
  cols, 
  function(col) ggplot(data = icadata, aes(x = !!sym(col))) + geom_histogram()
  )
names(p2) <- paste0(cols, "_histogram")

lapply(p2, class)
```

> ```
> $cyl_histogram
> [1] "gg"     "ggplot"
>
> $disp_histogram
> [1] "gg"     "ggplot"
>
> $wt_histogram
> [1] "gg"     "ggplot"
> ```

Comment: Sorry to bother you again.Can you explain !!sym(col) to me?Is it same with as.name()?